# What does come down mean in this sentence?

Tags: meaning-in-context

I was reading a short story and I found this phrasal verb so difficult to understand even with using Monolingual dictionary.

“Why don’t you **come down** to the pony farm with me tomorrow?“

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Up" and "down" are not only used to describe ascension and descent in terms of height. They are also used to describe travel north and south. For example, if you live north of somebody, you might say "come up and see me". Similarly, they might say "come down and see me". When travelling east and west, the alternative is "come over and see me".

Your example is specifically about a farm, and I have to say I am far more familiar with the expression "down on the farm" than any that contains "up". I wanted to add that this may be an idiom, that farms are always spoken of in terms of being lower land. However, [this ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=down%20on%20the%20farm%2Cup%20on%20the%20farm%2C%20down%20at%20the%20farm%2C%20up%20at%20the%20farm&year_start=1800&corpus=26&smoothing=3&year_end=2019&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cdown%20on%20the%20farm%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cup%20on%20the%20farm%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cdown%20at%20the%20farm%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cup%20at%20the%20farm%3B%2Cc0) shows that while that might have been the case at one time, expressions using "up" are now just as common.

Answer (score 0):

English is not my mother language but I will tell you my opinion.

"Come down" means to move down to the ground or to a lower level.It means to move downwards. Two synonyms of this phrasal verb are the verbs "descend" and "go down" .

The pony farm is at a lower position from the houses of the two persons.The speaker will go to the pony farm by his car or by his motorcycle and he wants to take his friend with him. Maybe there is a mountain and the pony farm is on the plain or at a lower position on the mountain.

"Come down" also means to travel south to the place where you are or to travel to a place that is further south. Maybe the two persons live north and they will travel south or they live south and they will travel to the pony farm that is further south.

The opposite of "come down" is "come up"."Come up" means to travel north to the place where you are . If someone comes up to a place, they travel north to the place where you are. We can say : "Why don't you come up to New York for the weekend?".We say this phrase to someone who is going to travel from south to north!

Additionally, I want to refer to the phrasal verb "come over" which means to travel from west to east or from east to west! We can say :"Come over and meet me at 'the island cafe' on Anexartisias street". We say this phrase to someone who is going to travel from east to west or from west to east!

Imagine that there is a block of flats. Someone is living on the highest floor and another person is living on a lower floor. Then the person who is living on the lower floor can say to the person who is living on the highest floor:"Come down to see me" or "Come over to see me".In this case "come over" means to go down!

Similarly, someone who is living south can say to somebody who is living north :"Come down to see me " or "Come over to see me" .